# C++ #define not work in multi .cpp program

Tags: c++, inline, preprocessor

I write a simply multi cpp files program using `#define` to control functions. like below:

1.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef HPP
#define HPP

#include <stdio.h>

inline void printdefine()
{
#ifdef PRINTS
    printf("define\n");
#endif
}

void print();
#endif
```

1.cpp

```cpp
#include"1.hpp"
void print()
{
    printdefine();
    printf("end");
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#define PRINTS
#include"1.hpp"

int main()
{
    printdefine();
    print();
}
```

then I run `g++ main.cpp 1.cpp -o 1.exe` and `./1.exe`, I get this input:

```
define
define
end
```

it is ok, but when I change `main.cpp` as below:

```cpp
#define PRINTS
#include"1.hpp"

int main()
{
    //printdefine();  changes here
    print();
}
```

the input is just `end`, like that the `#define PRINTS` does not work.

I guess it may be related to the inline function, I want to know what happended and how to control funtions body using `#define` in `main.cpp`.

Comment: Why would `#define` in one translation unit be sufficient?

Comment: Now is the time to learn about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit). A translation unit (or TU for short) is, simplified, a single source file with all included header files. It's the unit the compiler deals with. Macros exists only in the TU where they are defined.

Comment: You can add the definition for all files by including it in your compile string, e.g. for gcc/clang add `-DPRINTS` for VS (`cl.exe`) add `/DPRINTS`. IDEs also have a configuration dialog where you can set program defines. The other option is to make a common header included by all TUs (e.g. `defines.hpp` or `config.h`) and include that.

Comment: Since you have  a different definition of printdefine() in each of your two translation units, I believe ["the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) . Do what @DavidC.Rankin said. There is sort of a work around, but it would confuse everyone, including yourself, and might not give the results you want.

Comment: The expression is evaluated at compile time; the simplest fix here (for GCC) would be `-DPRINTS` in your command line.

Comment: It's illegal to have the same function defined two different ways in one program. This rule applies after the preprocessing step has completed (i.e. after the #defines have been applied).

Comment: You have two conflicting definitions of a function declared `inline` – besides from the programme being ill-formed apparently under the hoods the compiler opts for one version of the these two conflicting definitions. I'd assume main.cpp being compiled first, and when not calling the function the compiler just ignores the definition, then afterwards on compiling 1.cpp sees it without the `#define`. You might get more consistent results (never printing at all) if you reverse the order of compiling 1.cpp and main.cpp. That doesn't change anything about being ill-formed, though.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have pointed out, C and C++ use a concept called a "Translation Unit" which is the smallest unit for which all names the compiler deals with in a particular set of files must be defined. The guards `#ifndef HPP ... #endif` are designed so that the same names aren't inserted by the preprocessor into the same translation unit. For the most part, each separate file you give on a line to g++ will be in its own translation unit.

If you run g++, the preprocessor only runs once and performs macro expansion on files in the order they're listed. The consequences of this behavior can be seen by swapping the order of main.cpp and 1.cpp:

```
~/stackoverflow/define$ g++ 1.cpp main.cpp -o 1.exe ; ./1.exe
end
```

This is because when `1.cpp` is compiled, `PRINTS` hadn't been defined yet.

I don't know where in the spec this behavior is commented on, but I do know a simple solution: use a a separate header that contains the shared macro definitions. It's typically called `constants.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

#define PRINTS

#endif
```

Now we add this as the first include in each header in our project:

1.hpp:

```cpp
#ifndef HPP
#define HPP

#include "constants.h" // <-- new file
#include <stdio.h>

inline void printdefine()
{
#ifdef PRINTS
    printf("define\n");
#endif
}

void print();

#endif
```

(Side note: it just needs to be the first include of project files. It could have been placed after `#include <stdio.h>`)

Now it works as expected:

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include"1.hpp"

int main()
{
    //printdefine();
    print();
}
```

and then compiling it

```
~/stackoverflow/define$ g++ 1.cpp main.cpp -o 1.exe ; ./1.exe                          
define
end
```

This style is advantageous for another reason: build system flexibility. It isn't always clear how a build system will sequence compilation. While it requires more commands for a human programmer, this works just as well:

```
~/stackoverflow/define$ g++ -c main.cpp
~/stackoverflow/define$ g++ -c 1.cpp
~/stackoverflow/define$ g++ main.o 1.o -o 1.exe
~/stackoverflow/define$ ./1.exe
define
end
```

Here, the `-c` compiler switch means "compile only" and the compiler emits "object" code in files that end in `.o`.

If you take away `constants.h` from the project (remove the dependency on it) and compile the project like this, you'll see that commenting out `printdefine()` in `main.cpp` will have the same issue as before.

Comment: *'Simple solution'* – one way, actually simpler is just moving the `#define` into the header itself... Your variant comes with the advantage of – if consequently included – having a single location where you can configure the entire project (while you could do so, too, in a make-file or IDE's project file). *'If you take away'* – then you'd break the entire project because all the files there still try to include it. You might instead comment out the definition of `PRINTS` there ...

Comment: ... *or* – what I would prefer – `#define PRINTS 0` and test for via `#if PRINTS` instead of `#ifdef`. The former works, by the way, even if `PRINTS` is not defined at all, then the preprocessor assumes 0 as well.